# How to convert string colon-separated column to MapType?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a Dataframe to RDD in order to explode the map (with key-value pair) into different row.

```
Info = sqlContext.read.format("csv"). \
option("delimiter","\t"). \
option("header", "True"). \
option("inferSchema", "True"). \
load("file.tsv")

DataFrame[ID: int, Date: timestamp, Comments: string]
```

The sample data in the DF is as follows.

```
ID  Date                    Comments    
1   2015-04-30 22:42:49.0   {44:'xxxxxxxx'}
2   2015-05-06 08:53:18.0   {83:'aaaaaaaaa', 175:'bbbbbbbbb', 86:'cccccccccc'}
3   2015-05-13 19:57:13.0   {487:'yyyyyyyyyyy', 48:'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'}
```

Now, the comments are already in key-value pairs but it is read as a string, I want to explode each key-value pair into a different row. For e.g.

```
Expected OUTPUT
ID  Date                     Comments   
1   2015-04-30 22:42:49.0    {44:'xxxxxxxx'}
2   2015-05-06 08:53:18.0    {83:'aaaaaaaaa'}
2   2015-05-06 08:53:18.0    {175:'bbbbbbbbb'}
2   2015-05-06 08:53:18.0    {86:'cccccccccc'}
3   2015-05-13 19:57:13.0    {487:'yyyyyyyyyyy'}
3   2015-05-13 19:57:13.0    {48:'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'}
```

I have tried to convert it to a RDD and apply `flatMap` but to no success. I want all columns to be returned. I have tried this:

```
Info.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: (x['SearchParams'].split(':'), x))
```

Comment: Cheap trick : `df.withColumn("comments", split(regexp_replace(col("comments"), "," , "},{").as("comments") , ",").as("comments") )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the provided `split` and `explode` functions in the DataFrame API to split the data on ",". To create the map, you want to use `create_map`. This function expects two separate columns as input. Here below is an example were two temporary columns are created (again using `split`):

```
Info.withColumn("Comments", explode(split(col("Comments"), ", ")))
  .withColumn("key", split(col("Comments"), ":").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("value", split(col("Comments"), ":").getItem(1))
  .withColumn("Comments", create_map(col("key"), col("value")))
```

It should be possible to make this shorter like this (not tested):

```
Info.withColumn("Comments", split(explode(split(col("Comments), ", ")), ":")
  .withColumn("Comments", create_map(col("Comments".getItem(0)), col("Comments").getItem(1)))
```

Comment: Thanks Shaido. 

I referred to your suggestion and it works perfectly fine. Although I have created separate function for split and Explode.